# Re-distributing 2d data with max in middle

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

Hey all I have a set up seemingly random 2D data that I want to reorder. This is more for an image with specific values at each pixel but the concept will be the same.

I have large 2d array that looks very random, say:

```
x = 100
y = 120
np.random.random((x,y))
```

and I want to re-distribute the 2d matrix so that the maximum value is in the center and the values from the maximum surround it giving it sort of a gaussian fall off from the center.

small example:

```
    output = [[0.0,0.5,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.5,0.0]
              [0.0,1.0,1.0,1.5,1.0,0.5,0.0]
              [0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0,1.5,1.0,0.5]
              [0.0,1.0,1.0,1.5,1.0,0.5,0.0]
              [0.0,0.5,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.5,0.0]]
```

I know it wont really be a gaussian but just trying to give a visualization of what I would like. I was thinking of sorting the 2d array into a list from max to min and then using that to create a new 2d array but Im not sure how to distribute the values down to fill the matrix how I want.

Thank you very much!

Comment: So if the maximum value would initially be  *a[0][0]*, where would it be afterwards? *a[0][n / 2]* or to *a[m / 2][n / 2]* ?

Comment: Yes thats pretty much the idea

Comment: :) I was asking which one of the 2 possible variants is the preferred one.

Comment: Oh! sorry I read that wrong haha. So the max value would move to a[m/2][n/2] and ideally flow down radially from there to the same matrix size

Answer (score 1):

If anyone looks at this in the future and needs help, Here is some advice on how to do this effectively for a lot of data. Posted below is the code.

```
def datasort(inputarray,spot_in_x,spot_in_y):

    #get the data read
    center_of_y = spot_in_y                        
    center_of_x = spot_in_x
    M = len(inputarray[0])
    N = len(inputarray) 
    l_list = list(itertools.chain(*inputarray))    #listed data
    l_sorted = sorted(l_list,reverse=True)       #sorted listed data   

    #Reorder

    to_reorder = list(np.arange(0,len(l_sorted),1))
    x = np.linspace(-1,1,M)
    y = np.linspace(-1,1,N)
    centerx = int(M/2 - center_of_x)*0.01
    centery = int(N/2 - center_of_y)*0.01
    [X,Y] = np.meshgrid(x,y)
    R = np.sqrt((X+centerx)**2 + (Y+centery)**2)
    R_list = list(itertools.chain(*R))
    values = zip(R_list,to_reorder)
    sortedvalues = sorted(values)
    unzip = list(zip(*sortedvalues))
    unzip2 = unzip[1]
    l_reorder = zip(unzip2,l_sorted)
    l_reorder = sorted(l_reorder)
    l_unzip = list(zip(*l_reorder))
    l_unzip2 = l_unzip[1]
    sorted_list = np.reshape(l_unzip2,(N,M))
    return(sorted_list)
```

This code basically takes your data and reorders it in a sorted list. Then zips it together with a list based on a circular distribution. Then using the zip and sort commands you can create the distribution of data you wish to have based on your distribution function, in my case its a circle that can be offset.